# How do you update a cell based on an if statement?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, duplicates

I'm trying to update a cell value (cells in AA) to "Closed - duplicate" as long as column G = True (Duplicate Names) and Cancel Description (column AA) like "Closed". So basically if the duplicate name is the same and one of those rows has a "Closed" value under column AA, then update that cell to the new value. Here is what I got so far but for some reason its giving me an error and Im not sure why (see picture as reference):

Error occurs in this line of code:
If d = True And d.Offset(0, -7).Value = "*Closed*" Then

and the error says "Run Time Error 1004 - Application Defined or object defined error

[image]

```
Public Sub HighlightDuplicates()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Mwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngVis As Range
Dim rngVis2 As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim Table As ListObject
Set Mwb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Mwb.Worksheets("Commission")
Set Table = ws.ListObjects("Comm_Table")
    
LR = ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Table.ListColumns.Add 2
Table.HeaderRowRange(2) = "Duplicate ESIID"
ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT(--($A2=A:A))>1"
        
Set rngVis = ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each c In rngVis.cells
        If c = True Then
        c.EntireRow.Columns("A").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next c

Table.ListColumns(2).Delete

Table.ListColumns.Add 7
Table.HeaderRowRange(7) = "Duplicate Name"
ws.Range("G2:G" & LR).Value = "=SUMPRODUCT(--($F2=F:F))>1"

''This is where im having trouble:below''
Set rngVis2 = ws.Range("G2:G" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each d In rngVis2.cells
        If d = True And d.Offset(0, -7).Value = "*Closed*" Then
        d.EntireRow.Columns("AA").Value = "Closed - Duplicate"
        End If
    Next d**
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error (number, title and description) and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: If your comment starting `'for loop will ...` is a two line comment then you need a `'` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Just updated the post and my comment is just one line. When I copied and pasted, stack took it like that. I am not having issues with the first for loop.

Comment: This is your problem `d.Offset(0, -7)`. offsetting a cell in column G, 7 cells to the left is not a defined range as the first column (A) is 6 columns to the left. Which column is supposed to have the value `"*Closed*"`? Column AA?

Comment: Also are you trying to use regex? If so you need to use the `Like` operator instead of the `=` operator. `d.Offset(0, -7).Value Like "*Closed*"`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry correct, column AA should have values liked "*Closed*".

Comment: Then try `If d And d.Offset(0, 20).Value Like "*Closed*" Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update! instead of using my old approach, I decided to go with this for loop which seems to be much easier and more understandable to read and its doing what I was asking for.

```
    For i = 2 To Lr
     If ws.cells(i, "B").Value = "True" And ws.cells(i, "H").Value = "True" And 
      ws.cells(i, "AB").Value Like "*CLOSED*" Then
      ws.cells(i, "AB").Value = "CLOSED-DUPLICATE"
     End If
    Next i
```